# Weird issue tab id coupons_section is not instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0

I am struggling with weird problem when go to admin and click for add new rule code or edit a previously created shopping cart price rule en error is coming out

```
a:5:{i:0;s:29:"Test Wrong tab configuration.";i:1;s:2443:"#0 [internal function]: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->addTab('coupons_section', 'promo_quote_edi...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(347): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(345): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(270): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(263): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Promo/QuoteController.php(43): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Promo/QuoteController.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Promo_QuoteController->_initAction()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_Promo_QuoteController->editAction()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/vhosts/beadsofcambay.com/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}";s:3:"url";s:70:"/index.php/admin/promo_quote/new/key/accf713773b40d7a8531a365ea28cabe/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I have looked into the app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php

```
under the function addTab($tabId, $tab)
```

This condition is giving error where $tabId is coupon_section

```
 if(!($this->_tabs[$tabId] instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface)){
                    throw new Exception(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Test Wrong tab configuration.'));
                }
```

It was previously running perfect but don't know why this is giving error now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check if the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Coupons` implements `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface`. In the core code it does. Maybe someone modified it.

Second: Did you install any extensions related to discount rules? Maybe there is an extension that overrides `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Coupons` or that adds a block to this page with the same name (`promo_quote_edit_tab_coupons`).

Third: You can add this code before the exception is thrown and see what class is the tab.

```
if(!($this->_tabs[$tabId] instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface)){
     echo 'Wrong tab class is:'.get_class($this->_tabs[$tabId]);exit;//add this line
     throw new Exception(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Test Wrong tab configuration.'));
}
```

Instead of getting the error you should see the class of the tab and get an idea on what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marius.. it really help me i tried searching the class  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Coupons but wasn't present so i created the file  Coupons.php and worked.

Comment: This is really strange. You said that it worked some time ago, but just stopped working. If there is something that deleted the file there is a chance that there are other missing files. I recommend checking your files against a clean Magento instance. At least the ones in app/code/core

Comment: Yes i had check this in fresh installation but i didn't find the file there i am on 1.6.2 version but i tried your solution and tested it, it working just fine.